why sometimes first api request after some idle time take over 15s?
i have some api in .net core
configured everything i can so apppol is not recycled / always running etc

but still if i wait 10/15min betwen requests
first call takes >15s
and each next one 10ms
i did enabled logging to se what is taking this time
and i see that this is

-MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_SUCCESS_STATUS


how to trace why it is taking so long ?
what is it doing?
thanks and regards

you could use the debug diagnostic tool  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210 to collect the dump logs that might give you some information. could you check network tab and see which page on site is taking long time? may I know what failed request tracing rule you have applied? make sure you have installed Application Initialization feature of iis.

in IIS Manager, expand 'Sites' and right-click on your app.  Choose, "Manage Website>Advanced Settings".  Here there's a "Preload Enabled" option.  Set it to "true" to see if it helps (also be sure this is "in process" hosting).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-8.0#application-initialization-module

also note that if you publish "self-contained" you'll be "out of process"... I think if that's the case, you'd need to send a request every 20 minutes or so to keep it from idling out? (default idle timeout would be 20 minutes methinks)  You might also try using the "Enable ReadyToRun compilation" option in File Publish Options.

@browsermator it is self contained but i seted idle to 0 / it should do the trick to stop unload??

not sure... I don't think those settings apply, though:  "To prevent apps hosted out-of-process from timing out, use either of the following approaches:
Ping the app from an external service in order to keep it running.
If the app only hosts background services, avoid IIS hosting and use a Windows Service to host the ASP.NET Core app."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-8.0#idle-timeout

I may have misunderstood... I think only if it's a single-file build does it have to be out-of-process: "Apps published as a single file executable can't be loaded by the in-process hosting model."  You might be able to have self-contained run in process.  Though you may just want to run framework-dependent instead... I think running self-contained and in process can lead to crashes if hosting bundle and/or .net versions don't match the self-contained versions. (or if bit-ness of IIS app pool doesn't match)

for future searchers
it was waiting for .net to veryfy cert revocation list (probably some timeout on geting this list or something...)
the fix was
services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCertificate(
     o => 
     {
         o.RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck; 
     });

